# BizTalk 2010 Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.BizTalk.Interop.SSOClient

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Our server uses BizTalk 2010. Suddenly, we are receiving the following error:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.BizTalk.Interop.SSOClient, Version=10.0.1000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Other users that had this issue were usually trying to upgrade to a newer version of BizTalk. This is not the case here. We used version 2010 before, and are still using 2010.

Two things happened that may have to do with the sudden issues: there was a monthly windows patching round, and there was a deployment of a BizTalk application.

If anyone has any idea of how we can fix the Interop.SSOClient version, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Exactly where is this error being thrown from?   Is it just the newly installed application?   BizTalk 2010 should be using Version=5.0.1.0,  Microsoft.BizTalk.Interop.SSOClient, Version=10.0.1000.0, is for BizTalk 2016.  Has something you installed done a assembly redirect?

Comment: The newly installed application itself does not throw any errors. It's with other (WCF) applications within BizTalk. We are thinking something happened with the deployment (using the BizTalk Deployment Framework), in which it suddenly expects version 10.0.1000.0, while we have 5.0.1.0 installed. 

However, when we did a rollback of the deployment, the issue was not solved..

Answer (score 0):

You must have a version 10 reference of the SSOClient in your code base somewhere, i'd simply do a quick search in all files for the `Microsoft.BizTalk.Interop.SSOClient, Version=10.0.1000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35` string and see where you end up at...